# Square root and Cube root in the same equation

Tags: radicals

In a recent test I took, I received a question in an awkward form:
$$\sqrt y-\sqrt[3]{1000-y}=16$$
How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck (e.g. the comment under the answer by model_checker).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = \sqrt{y}$ and then you have that 
$$(x-16)^3 = 1000-x^2$$
which gives you a cubic that you can solve using standard methods.

Comment: I have tried this, and it leads me to $x^3 - 47 x^2 + 768 x - 5096 = 0$, which according to WolframAlpha doesn't have an integer solution.

Comment: @KaviAgrawal:  That is correct, it doesn't have an integral solution.  Why do you think it should?

Comment: How would I be able to derive the solution by hand, in that case?

Comment: Newton Ralphson is one iterative method that could be used to approximate roots.